# Congruence of Matrices in Knot theory

Tags: linear-algebra, knot-theory, matrix-congruences

I've been learning about knot theory lately and got stuck on a proof in Cromwells 'Knots and links', where some linear algebra is needed. For anyone interested its on pg. 158.

In the proof he wants to check for invariance for the Alexander-Polynomial under congruence. For congruence he writes:

$det(xP^TMP-x^{-1}(P^TMP)^T)=det(P^T(xM-x^{-1}M^T)P)=det(P^T)det(xM-x^{-1}M^T)det(P)$
$=det(xM-x^{-1}M^T)$

Were $M$ is a Seifert-Matrix and $P$ invertible.
He also writes earlier in the text that any symmetric matrix $A$ with entires in $\mathbb{R}$ is congruent to a diagonal matrix $B$ an that we can find an invertible orthogonal matrix $P$ with $det(P)=\pm 1$ so that $P^TAP=B$.

But in the proof we use any Seifert-Matrix and these don't have to be symmetric, so I don't see why  $det(P)$ should be $\pm1$.

What am I missing here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please don't use pictures. Use MathJax for the text, also the excerpt. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also give more context. Why can we assume $\det(P)=\pm 1$ for a symmetric matrix $M$? How are $P$ and $M$ connected? Can you please summarise the necessary details from page $158$?

Comment: $P$ is an invertible matrix with integer entries here, right? Invertible matrices have invertible determinants, and the only possibilities that are integers are $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: But why does the determinant of $P$ has to be an integer?

Comment: One reason: cofactor expansion doesn't involve division.